# Is it possible to have your flair displayed on all Stack Exchange websites?

Tags: feature-request, combined-flair

I want to have my Stack Exchange flair on all stack exchange websites. Is that possible? Can it be implemented?

Comment: Find your [flair here](https://stackexchange.com/users/15514439/haversine) and add it to your profile. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Possible, yes.

Considered off-topic as personal and not appropriate - also yes.

As the help center states:

> Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.
>
> Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card,
>   which links directly back to your user page. If you use an additional
>   signature or tagline, it will be removed to reduce noise in the
>   questions and answers.

However, on your profile, if you include (by copying and pasting):

```
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/15514439/haversine"><img src="https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/15514439.png" width="208" height="58" alt="profile for Haversine on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&amp;A sites" title="profile for Haversine on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&amp;A sites" /></a>
```

You get this:

[image: profile for Haversine on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

You will find the code [here.](https://stackexchange.com/users/15514439/haversine?tab=flair)

Paste it into your profile on a site say meta [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/15514439/haversine). You'll get the option to copy it onto all site's profiles.

As the help center sais:

> Your user page belongs to you — fill it with information about your
>   interests, links to stuff you’ve worked on, or whatever else you like!

Comment: Yes, my question was how I can make that flair appear as my profile when I post a question or answer. Is this possible?

Comment: Where do I post it on my profile? On the About me section?

Comment: so if i post my flair code there, it will show up on my profile?

Comment: What? I just edited it twice within 1 day and it saved...

Comment: Do you have any examples of people who have added flairs to their profiles so I can see how it looks like?

Comment: I see, did you use the html code on your profile?

Comment: @Haversine Yes, just paste it in there.